# Change collation of column without SET DATA TYPE

Tags: postgresql

I need to change column collation from default to "C.utf8".

This is the statement I am using:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ALTER COLUMN <column_name> SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR COLLATE "C.utf8";
```

The issue is that `SET DATA TYPE` is causing errors as there are views and triggers that rely on that specific column. I would rather not have to drop and recreate views and triggers and touch a lot of additional code-base. Is there a syntax for updating collation without requiring SET DATA TYPE?

Postgres version: 14.10

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way to do that. Modifying the catalog (and thereby corrupting any index on the column) might look appealing, but I deem that a foolhardy risk, since the proper solution is so simple: have a script that creates all your views (and is checked into a version control system). Then it is no problem to drop the views, run `ALTER TABLE` and create them again. You could do that in a single transaction.

Comment: Thank you. That is what we ended up doing. However, we didn't create any indexes on the column whose collation we wanted to change. Also, we use a migration tool, so the views and triggers need to have a change in the file hash for the tool to add them again. It just seems like a lot of unnecessary complexity for a column with no index.

Comment: I admit that that is unpleasant, but it avoids inconsistencies. We dislike data corruption so much that we risk annoying users to prevent it.